# Manipulating a list of data while keeping a history of all items

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

This is more of a general logic question, rather than anything specific to a language (although I'm using Web API, C#, and Entity Framework).

Here's the scenario. You have a list of items on a web page. Each item has multiple string fields that can be edited. Each item can be deleted, and new items can be created as well. Upon pressing a button, the web page will send the newly updated list of items via RESTful API to an application.

That application will receive the data, and then attempt to update a table in a database that it's connected to (via DbContext). If an item is updated, then the original table entry is updated. If an item is added, then a new table entry is inserted. (*The tricky part*) If an item is deleted, then the table entry will have some indicator that it's simply historical data now and should not be active.

For me, the difficulty is comparing the list of items from the POST request to items in the database table and then dealing with each item accordingly (without doing a hack job).

*Note:* upon GET request, the application should be able to determine which items are historic and which aren't so it can only pull non-historic.

Response are appreciated! Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about storing id-s of items on client-side (while not showing them off course) and tracking the state of each item (added, updated, deleted, unchanged). Then you can post this info together with all items and react accordingly on server.

And soft deletion is a rather simple task, you can just google soft deletes.

Additionally, you can have a view in DB to filter out historical data (with `WHERE DELETED = 0` filter) and just redirect all your data-selection to this view.